# Multiple Values in Custom Template Field

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have a custom template for a node, and a field which has the possibility of having multiple pieces of data. In this case:

- There is an Author node
- There are Publication nodes
- Publications are being Entity Referenced on the Author node

The custom template then prints the publications to the node

```
<?php print render($content['field_publications']); ?>
```

I know that adding `['1']` displays the first publication if multiple publications are attached to the same author, however, how would I display the top 5 publications, if say, there was 10 publications by the same author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice the array?

```
foreach(array_slice($content['field_publications'], 0, 5) as $field_publication):
```